# Is direct commit to master branch allowed in GitFlow workflow?

Tags: git, git-flow

Is direct commit to master branch allowed in GitFlow workflow or should master branch contain only merge commits from other branches (develop, hotfix, release and feature branches)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally and theoretically, you should not commit anything directly to the master branch. As you've said, you should merge the commit from an other branch.

But practically, nothing stops you from doing so, because after all, it's a standard git branch, even if it's created using gitflow workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me in what GitFlow scenarios it is ok to do commit directly to master? Is it for minor changes, small fixes, typo corrections etc...or larger changes are fine too? Also, once commit is added to master, what other branches then these changes on master be merged into?

Comment: The thing is, when using gitflow workflow, you're not supposed to bypass the other branches.

Branches are made for the different types of updates, if it's a new feature, you've got the feature branches, if it's a small critical change, you've got to work on the hotfix branch, if it's some minor change, you can directly work on the develop branch etc..

In other words you should manage the changes and the code, in a good way, such that each change is done in the proper branch.

To answer your question, if you push something directly to master, no other branch will be updated.